# Help to learn words

Tags: dictionary, memory-management

I have list of words and translations I would like to learn. I need software that could help me to learn them by asking translations or original words. I don't need any lessons, and tutorials, just memorizing tool. Web or desktop application.

Comment: You might want to googled them first, if still can't, come back here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/)? I haven't used it for a long time but it's cross platform (including smartphones and anything that can use web apps) and you can create your own decks of flash cards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some form of Flashcard memorization tool, like [Mnemosyne](https://mnemosyne-proj.org).

> The Mnemosyne Project has two aspects:
>
> - It's a free flash-card tool which optimizes your learning process.
> - It's a research project into the nature of long-term memory. We strive to provide a clear, uncluttered piece of software, easy to use
>     and to understand for newbies, but still infinitely customisable
>     through plugins and scripts for power users.